# React native BottomTabNavigation in BottomTabNavigation

Tags: react-native

I'm building a react-native app. Basically, it has a BottomTabNavigation for navigating through the screens.

In one of my screens, I want to open another screen with a BottomTabNavigation to navigate to other screens inside.

Unfortunately, I haven't found something on Google or in the search function. Is this possible to create?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily using a module called [react-native-best-viewpager](https://github.com/abbasmoosavi/react-native-best-viewpager)!

Install with:

`npm install --save react-native-best-viewpager` or with `yarn install react-native-best-viewpager` if you're using yarn.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```js
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {PagerTabIndicator, IndicatorViewPager} from 'react-native-best-viewpager';

export default class ViewPagerPage extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{flex:1}}>
                <IndicatorViewPager
                    style={{flex:1, paddingTop:20, backgroundColor:'white'}}
                    indicator={this._renderTabIndicator()}
                >
                    <View style={{backgroundColor:'cadetblue'}}>
                        <Text>page one</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{backgroundColor:'cornflowerblue'}}>
                        <Text>page two</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{backgroundColor:'#1AA094'}}>
                        <Text>page three</Text>
                    </View>
                </IndicatorViewPager>
            </View>
        );
    }



    _renderTabIndicator() {
        let tabs = [{
                text: 'Home',
                iconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_home_normal.png'),
                selectedIconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_home_click.png')
            },{
                text: 'Message',
                iconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_task_normal.png'),
                selectedIconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_task_click.png')
            },{
                text: 'Profile',
                iconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_my_normal.png'),
                selectedIconSource: require('../imgs/ic_tab_my_click.png')
        }];
        return <PagerTabIndicator tabs={tabs} />;
    }

}
```